# how to create a commun database with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new at firebase. I want a common database to all users. 
I successfully integrated firebase with Realm in my project. 
Now I'm adding objects with code, successfully.
 the problem is that everytime I launch or restart the app, the code is executed and new objects are created.
 This is not what I want, I want the objects to be common for all users in the database. 
how can I create objects, only one time with Realm Firebase?

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: what for? I'm not having problem with the code. I'am asking if there's a way to create objects only once and they still be common to all users with Firebase?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, you can create objects once and be common to all users with Firebase. However, without seeing how you've implemented your code, we won't be able to tell you what the issue is or provide an answer as it would just be guess work. Take a minute and review the guides [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked around and the answer is no , you can not create objects once in for all, for different users only one time, with code, from client mobile applications.

So there are two options to create only once a common database in firebase
ans there are:

1. populate objects directly from the fire base console
2. create an admin app responsible for the objects creation

Comment: This is not correct. You absolutely can create once and 're-use' that object. While code-wise the object will go out of scope and then back in scope when the app reloaded - the object would be 'new' but populated with it's last state of data so it would be seamless. You can think of the object keeping a snapshot of itself and restoring it's state when it is created again. You can do that with data stored in both Firebase and Realm but it's unclear why you are using both and frankly may be an unnecessary duplication of data.

Comment: I'm using Firebase with Realm, there will be no duplication of data.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I can't see how it could possibly be done, could  you please post an example of how such code is to be written?, what do you mean by code-wise?

Comment: You cannot 'use Firebase with Realm' other than Firebase is being used for authentication. Firebase and Realm are two completely independent products, have separate API's and are unrelated in pretty much every way except they are both databases.

Comment: Objects in code can be populated from either and could appear to persist between application launches in a variety of ways - from storing the data in either Firebase or Realm (or both?) to writing objects to a local file and restoring them on next app launch. I can't provide any code because it's not clear what *I want the objects to be common for all users in the database* means. Please clarify your use in the initial question and maybe we can point you in the right direction.